# Oracle connections from a COM+ application

Tags: oracle, com+

We have an Oracle 10.2.0 server running. There is a schema on the server called FOO. I have created an ODBC connection to the schema using the 10.2.0 client.

We have a desktop application that has core database access libraries written by ourselves that uese SQLDriverConnect etc.

We also have a COM+ application that makes use of the same core libraries.

When I connect with the desktop application, using the ODBC connection, there are no problems.

Connecting with the COM+ application, I cannot perform any queries. SQLDriverConnect returns SUCCESS but then any attempt to peform a query gives an Oracle error "not connected". The COM+ application is set to run as the "logged in user".

I'm sure this is probably a security issue, but I don't know where to start.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What programming language? Show code that causes error.

Comment: The first thing I would do is install the COM+ app on the same server the Oracle DB is installed. This will eliminate most security issues (privileges, firewalls etc.), and let you make sure the rest works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was causing the problem, it's an Oracle bug.

Cause: 
Oracle Bug 4991478; COM application not able to connect when using Oracle10g Client 10.2 if using Neutral Threading or Free-Threaded Marshaller, Fails With ORA-21561 / ORA-00022

Solution: 
Install Oracle Client (patch) 10.2.0.3.0.